# Find a percentile of a datetime range

Tags: sql, datetime

I have a data set like this:

```
problem_id -- aspect_type -- time_created
28 -- requirement -- 9/9/2013 16:44
28 -- requirement -- 9/9/2013 18:47
28 -- artifact -- 9/9/2013 20:32
35 -- artifact -- 9/5/2013 1:52
35 -- artifact -- 9/9/2013 12:06
35 -- function -- 9/9/2013 11:55
```

For each problem_id, I want to find the dominant aspect_type in a specific range of time during the creation of all the aspects. For example, in the set above, for problem 28 the first and the second quarter are dominated by type 'requirement', and the last quarter is dominated by type 'artifact'.
To do so, first I wanted to determine the time range. I could get the beginning of the last quartile with the following:

```
cast(max(created)-(max(created)-min(created))/4 as datetime) as last_quartile
```

But this only worked for things that were created in the same day like problem 28. I would get null for other problem id's like 35.  The (max-min)/4 was a number like '1993964.0000000000' or '3402.7500000000' which I assume is in seconds. I could get this for all entries, but once I tried to add this to a start datetime or subtract it from an end datetime I would get null for those types not added in the same day.
Is there a more straightforward way to define a range of datetime , like the third 20 percent between 2013-09-03 18:17:20 and 2013-09-06 08:37:34, and then count occurrences of an attribute in that range?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: MySQL; I'm working in MySQL Workbench

Answer (score 0):

For the date/time when the last quartile begins, try something like:

```
max(created) - interval timestampdiff(second, max(created), min(created)) / 4 second
```

Comment: Thanks. The following gave me what I wanted: DATE_SUB(max(created), Interval ROUND(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,min(created),max(created))/4) DAY_SECOND)